# How to set particular value to a dropdown the angular way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a simple angular dropdown like bellow:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="docPropIdentityModel.OwnerLevel"
         ng-options="ownerLevel as ownerLevel.LevelName for ownerLevel in ownerLevels track by ownerLevel.OwnerLevelID">
         <option value="">--Select--</option>
</select>
```

I've a value for OwnerLevelID, I want to assign the OwnerLevelID as the value of the dropdown & show the respective LevelName. I can easily do this by using jquery but want to do it the angular way.

I tried to assign the value for the model like bellow:

```
$scope.docPropIdentityModel.OwnerLevel = "123456";
```

But it didn't work. How it can be done?

Comment: `$scope.docPropIdentityModel.OwnerLevel = { OwnerLevelID : "123456"};`

Comment: are you sure that `OwnerLevelID` is a `string` and not a `number`? `$scope.docPropIdentityModel.OwnerLevel = 123456;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using `track by` expression, You need to set the `OwnerLevelID` property of object associated with `ngModel`.

```
$scope.docPropIdentityModel.OwnerLevel = { OwnerLevelID : "123456"};
```

[image: jsFiddle]

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        angular.module("myapp", [])
          .controller("MyController", function ($scope) {
              $scope.register = {};
              $scope.register.countryId = "4";

              $scope.register.countries = [{
                  id: "1",
                  name: "India"
              }, {
                  id: "2",
                  name: "USA"
              }, {
                  id: "3",
                  name: "UK"
              }, {
                  id: "4",
                  name: "Nepal"
              }];
          });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myapp">
    <div ng-controller="MyController">
        <div>
            Country Name :  <select ng-model="register.countryId" ng-options="country.id as country.name for country in register.countries"></select>
        </div>
        <div>
            Country-Id : {{register.countryId}}
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```